# How do I disable SSLV3 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I run the following command (identifying the host and port) via terminal and get connected, so SSLV3 is still enabled on my Ubuntu box but I can't find any resource on how to disable it.

openssl s_client -connect : -ssl3

I need to only allow TLS1+ and disable SSLv3 so when I run the above command I get handshake failed when I specify -ssl3

Thanks for your input.....

Comment: what client ?  It varies with the client

Comment: I am just running the following:openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> -ssl3 and it handshakes instead of failing which means that sslv3 is enabled on my server.  All the forums I read show ways to disable things like apache or firefox etc... is there a way to deny sslv3 at the openssl level?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us anything about what your server is running. OpenSSL is a library. It can take various options which are fed to it via the application that is using it - so configuration depends on the application. Assuming you are using Apache with mod_ssl then you probably want to look at the [SSLProtocol directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslprotocol). This is probably the easiest way to do it.

It is also possible to configure OpenSSL without SSLv3 at compile time. Obviously that means you have to compile it and install it yourself rather than using the out-of-the-box ubuntu version. To do that download the latest version from [the OpenSSL website](https://www.openssl.org/source/). Unzip and untar the source file and move into the created openssl directory. Enter the following:

```
./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-ssl3-method
make
make test
make install
```

By default that will install into /usr/local/ssl. You will need to configure your application's LD_LIBRARY_PATH to pick up the libraries from this location rather than the default system version.